# Can Windows Server 2012 run all Metro (/ Windows Store) applications?

Tags: windows-8, compatibility, modern-ui, windows-server-2012

I plan to use Windows Server 2012 Standard on my PC as my primary OS.

Can Windows Server 2012 run all Metro (/ Windows Store) applications or are there arbitrary limitations or edition checks that might limit the number of available apps?

**Update**

Some DLLs are just missing on Server 2012 and Metro games and videos all crash *until* you install them http://www.win2012workstation.com/xinput-and-xaudio-dlls/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issues I know of right now regarding using Windows Store on Server 2012 are:

- Store can't be run as Administrator.
- Many other apps also can't be run as Administrator. These apps appear grayed out on the Start screen. One that comes to mind is Google Chrome; it can't be run as a Windows 8 app as Administrator (but it can run as a desktop app, started from a desktop shortcut).
- Only a very few apps make the distinction between Server 2012 and Windows 8. Typically these are antivirus apps; you will have to do some serious shopping to find an antivirus program that works with Server 2012 and isn't designed for business environments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On the same day I asked the question I started using Windows Server 2012 on my laptop giving it Windows 8 treatment and it just works beautifully. My university provides Sophos to its staff so I am covered on that front as well. Some metro apps, such as mail, used to crash often but it received 2 updates already and now is rock solid. For some reason I cannot get Metro apps to play videos though.

Comment: Dunno about videos. Nearly everything I run is a desktop app.

Comment: I don't care much about it either for the time being. Busy loving the *heaven into* Haskell / F# and HTML5+CSS3+JS these days. There is always VLC to cover my entertainment needs. Oh I had also used Windows 2008 R2 like Windows 7 before and can just as well report that it does run all PC games without a single complaint.